# When setting up a campaign, Facebook is crawling my website using an Iphone user agent

Tags: web-crawlers, facebook, crawl-errors, campaigns

Whenever I'm I'm setting up a campaing on Facebook, I get two visits from Facebook's auto crawlers.

The first one I can identify as a robot and serve the SSR (HTML) version to it.

The user agent is:

> userAgent: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)

[image]

But after **500ms** (see screenshots) it visits my website again with an Iphone user-agent, which I cannot properly identify as a robot:

The user agent is:

> userAgent: mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 13_3_1 like mac os x) applewebkit/605.1.15 (khtml, like gecko) version/13.0.5 mobile/15e148 safari/604.1

[image]

And since I cannot identify it as a robot, it gets the full Javascript version of my website (which is a Single Page App) **with the code for the Analytics logging events. So it shows on my Analytics reports.**

Usually it shows the location from **Irvine - California.**

[image]

And it's a bounce, since it only visits a single page.

Is this normal? Has anyone seen this before?

I apparently only happens when I'm setting up a campaign on Facebook. When I'm posting links, it only crawls with the robot user agent.